# Anythingslider continuous slide jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anythingslider

It has been a while, at the moment I am trying to learn jquery step by step.
In the meanwhile I am leaning in favor of anythingslider for the moment as it quickens the process for the time being.

I am using jquery 1.7.2 as you can see and have read the documents here: *I lack reputation to post a third link and traded this link for the solved section*.

However, if one is unable to help me out with anythingslider, is there an interesting alternative and if possible a learning example where i can build this from scratch.

What I am trying to achieve is in this example: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/23/

I am unable to find help on the internet in how to achieve this effect, any advice references or examples are most appreciated regarding this effect.

**Solved:** I have found an alternative and it seems that this is not built into the standard Jquery library, I was unable to find any answer regarding this effect. However I have found the following and would like to share it, if an admin decides to delete the topic, feel free to do so. For now i will leave it if anyone else would stumble upon the idea of creating this effect.
Enjoy! : http://smoothdivscroll.com/

My script code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.anythingslider.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
    buildArrows : true,
    autoPlay : true, 
    infiniteSlides: true,
    buildStartStop : false,
    resizeContents: false ,
    delayBeforeAnimate: 0, 

});

}); 

</script>
```